# How to solve this Problem while running a Flutter App?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

In a online course we've created a simple Flutter App in Android Studio. We downloaded a package (audioplayers) and built a simple AudioPlayer that makes a noice whenever someone taps a button.
But when im trying to run the App on the iOS Simulator, Android Studio shows me this errors. I have absolutely here no idea how to solve these.

This is the error message:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Removing obsolete reference to flutter_assets from Runner.app
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
  sudo gem install cocoapods

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            3,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: /Users/luisrotzoll/AndroidStudioProjects/xylophone-flutter/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

I hope someone here in this big community can help me fix this error! Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the error telling you whats missing and how to fix it? try as it says running`sudo gem install cocoapods` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows maybe you should install the coco pods using the given command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```